# This script won't find Absolute Urls

Tags: php, arrays, url

in the code below, it is supposed to scan links and index them in the array [links]. but for some reason, they won't index.

I am starting to think if my regex code is wrong, how can i improve it. Also is it my file_get_contents command? Is it used correctly?

```
$links = Array();

$URL = 'http://www.theqlick.com'; // change it for urls to grab  

// grabs the urls from URL 
$file  = file_get_contents($URL);

    $abs_url = preg_match_all("'^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$^'", $file, $link);
    if (!empty($abs_url)) {
        $links[] = $abs_url;
    }
```

Comment: Look at the docs for [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). The third parameter is where the result gets saved.

Answer (score 0):

In your preg_match_all you are saving into $link not $links.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred (c) php.net

```
preg_match_all("'^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$^'", $file, $matches);

if (!empty($matches)
  $links = $matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong. You have a head anchor `^` at the end of the pattern adjacent to a tail match `$`. I don't think the anchors really aren't needed. Additionally, your variable you are storing matches in `$link` (no `s`). Plus your pattern delimiter appears to be the `'` character. Was that intentional? It would fortunately work, but I'm guessing you didn't intend for that?

Try this:

```
$matchCount = preg_match_all("/(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/", $file, $matches);
if ($matchCount)
{
    foreach ($matches as $match)
    {
        $links[] = $match[0];
    }
}
```

Read up on [PHP regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).